# Make Nagios graphs public

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, nagios, cgi

I have a Nagios instance running on Ubuntu Server Lucid as a VM monitoring our Windows network.

I would like to have some specific graphs made by the trends.cgi file available on the internal Intranet. However when I make a link to one of these Apache/Nagios requires credentials to access these (makes sense).

How can I make it so that non authed users can request graphs without having to login to Nagios. I also don't want just give access to anything I don't have to.

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/183945/apache-basic-authentication-auth-not-required-for-some-files

Answer (score 2):

The webpage is simply invoking RRD to draw the graph from the data file. You could setup another virtual server just for displaying the graphs that you want and keep it pretty basic on security. I can't imagine it would be terribly difficult. Sorry I don't have specifics but maybe that will kick you in the right direction.